# Docs Add-on, having trouble with the OAuth Consent Screen Setup, Only using GAS and reference to a Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to submit my Google add-on for verification, which only uses GAS scripts and no external services. However, when I get to the OAuth consent screen tab, I'm asked to provide Authorized Domains. I'm not sure what to put in this field as I'm only using a Google Sheet and a Google Drive image within the add-on.

I've carefully read the documentation, but I still don't understand what to add. When I left the field blank, it shows "Missing domain: google.com". I also tried adding the googleusercontent.com addresses for the sheet and image, but it's always flagged as "Invalid domain: must be a top private domain."

Can someone please provide guidance on what to include in the Authorized Domains field for a Google add-on that uses only GAS scripts and resources stored on Google Sheet and Drive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add `google.com` as your app domain? As far as I can tell you should be able to leave the "Authorized domains" field empty unless you have also selected an app domain above.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I had added google.com and got an email back from them saying "It looks like the following domain isn't owned by you or your project. Please remove this domain..."  When then go to the OAuth verification page, it says what I've written above about "Missing domain" :(

Thank you for sharing this thought!  If you have any other ideas, I would appreciate hearing them.

Comment: Did you try to remove Google from the domains and just leaving it without any domains at all?

Comment: @Daniel
I was trying to use a Google Site as the location of the privacy and terms of service statements. I discovered that is why it was saying I needed google.com as an authorized domain. I switched to a purchased URL and it stopped asking for google.com. I couldn't leave the domain empty because the location of the privacy and TOS statements must be on the authorized domains list.

I've not seen any more response from them since I submitted it again for verification, so I didn't want to report that this solves the problem yet.  

Thanks for sharing another idea with me